# User is not properly logged in Kohana with Auth module

Tags: authentication, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-auth

I'm using the Auth module for managing users inside Kohana.

When I use the login($username, $password, $remember) method it succeeds validating the user but then when I ask if the users is logged in (logged_in() method) it returns false.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check user for roles (`login` role is required by default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing logged_in does for the default Auth driver is check if there is an active session with a proper key that points to a logged in user.

Your question is too global to be able to give a direct answer, but it might be that the problem stems from improper Cookie settings. Your session will always be saved in a Cookie and if the cookie path and/or domain are not properly setup, then the session will be invalid and Auth::instance()->logged_in() will return false.

Check this link for setting up cookies in Kohana: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/cookies

Comment: It was a problem with the sessions configuration. I changed the $default variable from 'native' to 'database' on the system/kohana/session.php file. Thank you very much!

Comment: You should accept his answer if it's correct. I'd bet your problem was down to the sessions table not having the correct data types for the fields.